# Retrieving MSIEXEC exit code in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I need to run an `MSIEXEC` command line from a PowerShell and check whether the installation was successful or not.

If I do:

```
msiexec.exe /qn /l*v e:/tmp/surfaceruntime.log  /i '\\nas\lui\tools\surfaceruntime2.msi'
```

(where the specified MSI doesn't exist – that's for testing purposes)

I get a `$LASTEXITCODE` of 1

OTOH, if I do:

```
$parms=@("/qn", "/l*v", "e:/tmp/surfaceruntime.log";"/i";"\\nas\lui\tools\surfaceruntime2.msi") 

$run=[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("msiexec",$parms) 
$run.WaitForExit() 
$run.ExitCode
```

I get 1619 (same as `%ERRORLEVEL%` if I run the command line from `CMD`).

How come `$LASTEXITCODE` is incorrect?

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
(Start-Process -FilePath msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $parms -Wait -Passthru).ExitCode
```